# Pip install in virtualenv throws warnings

Tags: python, django, heroku, virtualenv, pip

```
   pip install Django psycopg2 dj-database-url
```

I get this response:

```
Downloading/unpacking Django
  Downloading Django-1.4.1.tar.gz (7.7MB): 7.7MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Django

Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.4.5.tar.gz (719kB): 719kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/src/_build'
Downloading/unpacking dj-database-url
  Downloading dj-database-url-0.2.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package dj-database-url

Installing collected packages: Django, psycopg2, dj-database-url
  Running setup.py install for Django
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/django-admin.py from 644 to 755

    changing mode of /Users/kristoffernolgren/web/venv/bin/django-admin.py to 755
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/green.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/utils.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:81:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33:
    ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:81:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33:
    ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    psycopg/cursor_type.c:435:58: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        tmp = pq_execute(self, Bytes_AS_STRING(self->query), async);
              ~~~~~~~~~~                                     ^~~~~
    psycopg/cursor_type.c:773:44: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        res = _psyco_curs_buildrow(self, self->row);
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~       ~~~~~~^~~
    psycopg/cursor_type.c:820:44: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        res = _psyco_curs_buildrow(self, self->row);
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~       ~~~~~~^~~
    psycopg/cursor_type.c:899:48: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            row = _psyco_curs_buildrow(self, self->row);
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~       ~~~~~~^~~
    psycopg/cursor_type.c:959:27: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        size = self->rowcount - self->row;
             ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
    psycopg/cursor_type.c:969:48: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            row = _psyco_curs_buildrow(self, self->row);
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~       ~~~~~~^~~
    psycopg/cursor_type.c:1143:32: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                newpos = self->row + value;
                       ~ ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
    7 warnings generated.
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    In file included from psycopg/notify_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33:
    ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from psycopg/notify_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33:
    ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33:
    ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33:
    ./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    In file included from psycopg/typecast.c:179:
    ./psycopg/typecast_array.c:227:31: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                if (--stack_index < 0)
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from psycopg/typecast.c:179:
    ./psycopg/typecast_array.c:227:31: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                if (--stack_index < 0)
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~
    1 warning generated.
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-F. -arch i386 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
    ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/lib/libpq.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/lib/libpq.dylib

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/src/_build'
  Running setup.py install for dj-database-url

Successfully installed Django psycopg2 dj-database-url
Cleaning up...
pip install Django psycopg2 dj-database-url
```

Everything works fine, but I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Those appear to be warnings, not errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are warnings. I'm not really familiar with GCC options nowadays (I have last used c/c++ more than two years ago) but they generally depend on some flags and style checks.

For example, while compiling, `-Wunused-function` option is provided to the compiler so it prints a warning whenever there is an unused function found. The other warning says `-mno-fused-madd flag` is not used presumably because the compiler does not know what to do with it.

These could happen because `psycopg library` authors forgot to update the build file (a `Makefile`I assume) and they forgot to remove unused functions. It could also happen because of compiler variations, your compiler may be using different set of default flags for example. From my experience these could happen on Mac OS since they have a bit different way of doing things, in contrast with Linux.

If everything is working no worries but if you receive some kind of errors you should look into it to see if you can get rid of the warnings somehow.